# When $A-B$ is an invertible matrix

Tags: matrices

True or false: If $\det(A-B)\neq 0$ for $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices.
I think that this assertion is false, but I don't find a good counterexample.

Comment: Consider if $A$ is invertible and $B$ is the zero matrix. Then $\det(A-B)\ne 0$ but it is *not* true that $A$ **and** $B$ are invertible matrices.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541634/if-a-and-b-are-invertible-matrices-is-ab-invertible-too/2541665#2541665 for the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the $2 \times 2$ matrices

```
1 0   0  0
0 0   0 -1
```